# Enable Multiprocess WebView programmatically on Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

How do we toggle the Multiprocess WebView switch programmtically? Right now the current implementation runs in the same process this log verifies that

`I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true`

I can't access the developer options menu because we use a custom AOSP implementation where launching the developer options intent crashes as there is no activity which handles it.

Has anyone encountered stuff like this before? An alternatives that I can look into?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361262/toggle-webview-multiprocess-flag-does-not-take-effect. This setting seems to have been silently removed after Android Nougat. At any rate this has never been a flag that could be set programmatically. It was kind of experimental option for an experienced user to try.

Comment: Check this document: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/renderer/README.md There should be a way to switch by ADB