# Toggle WebView Multiprocess flag does not take effect

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm turning on MultiProcess WebView flag using

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Global.WEBVIEW_MULTIPROCESS, 1);
```

Also, querying for the same returns `1` which means the flag is set.

This is done before my WebView is initialized, but the WebView logs print it as running in single process

```
I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I do not see `WEBVIEW_MULTIPROCESS` in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global).

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm able to reference it. I'm using compileSdkVersion 27

Comment: The fact that it was removed from the SDK suggests that the System WebView perhaps no longer honors it.